# If div contains another (or child) div with class "key" then change color of clicked div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with class "section-a" containing divs for buttons of class "key" and their corresponding values.

I need to iterate through these "key" divs, and change the color of the clicked div only.

Please see the extract:

```
<div class="keyboard">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="section-a">
      <div class="key function space1">
        esc
      </div>

      <div class="key function">
        F1
      </div>
      <div class="key function">
        F2
      </div>
      <div class="key function">
        F3
      </div>
```

So if you were to click on F1, the color of the font would turn green, and back to white if you click the button (or another button) again.

I understand you need to use toggleClass but the problem is to iterate through the divs containing the class key.

Another solution (but not the best in programming practices) would to add an onclick event to each button, which would be easy but not very DRY.

The closest I have come was to use:

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $('div[class*="key"]').css('color', 'green');
});
```

but in turn this does not select the current clicked element.

I am very sure i am missing something simple here!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please find the working snippet below. You don't need to iterate, with jQuery you can modify classes of an array of elements, in this case, of every element that contains the class `key`. And on the click event listener, `$(this)` will refer to the element that was clicked so you can add the highlighted class directly to it.

```js
$('body').on('click', '.key', function(){
  $('.key').removeClass('highlighted');
  $(this).addClass('highlighted');
});
```

```css
.highlighted{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="section-a">
  <div class="key function space1">esc</div>
  <div class="key function">F1</div>
  <div class="key function">F2</div>
  <div class="key function">F3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code if correct, thanks, but the problem was actually my CDN, it was not loading the JQuery lib so your code didnt seem to work. Thanks for such a detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
$('body').click('.key',function(e){
    $('div.key').css('color', 'green');
    $('div.key').not(e.target).css('color', '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="keyboard">
  <div class="section">     
      <div class="section-a">
            <div class="key function space1">
             esc
            </div>

            <div class="key function">
              F1
            </div>
            <div class="key function">
              F2
            </div>
            <div class="key function">
              F3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('div[class*="key"]').on("click",function(){
    $('div[class*="key"]').each(function(){
      $(this).css("color","black");
    });
    $(this).css("color","green")
  });
```